# Send emails triggered automatically by date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet in the following link:

[Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Pqhq5wgLR5NLz_fhvOtKnu3dQ0cMK_j_vKbR736to4/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to send emails automatically triggered by a date in a cell. I have created code but can't get it to work.

The body of the email is in cell A1 of the "Email Alerts" Sheet.

In the "H&S Reviews" Sheet:

```
Column K = the trigger date
Column I = the email address
Column J = the "name" for the email
Column C = the "Task" for the body of the email
Column G = the "Date" the review is due for the body of the email
Column D = the "Description" for the body of the email
```

The code is called function sendEmails from line 339 to 367 per below:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("H&S Reviews").activate();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var message = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email Alerts").getRange(1,1).getValue();

  // I modified below script.
  var values = sheet.getRange(4, 1, lastRow - 3, 11).getValues();
  var todaysDate = sheet.getRange(1, 11).getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var [,,task,description,,,date,,emailAddress,firstName,sendDate] = values[i];
    var messageBody = message.replace("{name}",firstName).replace("{Task}",task).replace("{Description}",description).replace("{Date}",date);
    var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task"; 
    var sheetDate = new Date(sendDate);
    Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate,"GMT+0200","dd-MM-yyyy");
    SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,"GMT+0200", "dd-MM-yyyy");
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task";
      emailAddress = "tga.assist@uzabus.co.nz";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);
    }
  }
}
```

Also when I run the code in the Script Editor I get the following message:

*"Method SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue is heavily used by the script.Collapse
File: Code Line: 344
The script uses a method which is considered expensive. Each invocation generates a time consuming call to a remote server. That may have critical impact on the execution time of the script, especially on large data. If performance is an issue for the script, you should consider using another method, e.g. Range.getValues()."*

I would really appreciate some help to get this working.

Comment: When you say that you want the emails to be automatically triggered by date.  What you you mean by that?

Comment: I want emails to be sent when the date in each row from K3 down matches the date in cell K1 which = today's date.

Comment: Yes I finally figured that out.  that's working now

Comment: I set some of the dates in column K3:K to equal the date in K1 then ran the script but didn't receive any emails. When I looked at the Apps Script Dashboard, the status of the function is 'completed' but "No Logs available for execution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- In your script, `getValue()` is used in the for loop. By this, I think that this occurs such issue. So in this modification, `getValues()` is used instead of `getValue()` as mentioned by the error message.

#### Modified script:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("H&S Reviews").activate();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var message = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Email Alerts").getRange(1,1).getValue();

  // I modified below script.
  var values = sheet.getRange(4, 1, lastRow - 3, 11).getValues();
  var todaysDate = sheet.getRange(1, 11).getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var [,,task,description,,,date,,emailAddress,firstName,sendDate] = values[i];
    var messageBody = message.replace("{name}",firstName).replace("{Task}",task).replace("{Description}",description).replace("{Date}",date);
    var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task"; 
    var sheetDate = new Date(sendDate);
    Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate,"GMT+0200","dd-MM-yyyy");
    SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,"GMT+0200", "dd-MM-yyyy");
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var subject = "Health & Safety Review Task";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);
    }
  }
}
```

- Before the for loop, the values are retrieved from the Spreadsheet. And the retrieved values are used in the for loop.

#### Note:

- In your script, as the range of `H&S Reviews`, the values are retrieved from the row 4. So I reflected this to the modified script. If you want to retrieve the values from the row 3, please modify `var values = sheet.getRange(4, 1, lastRow - 3, 11).getValues();` to `var values = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow - 2, 11).getValues();`.
- I think that in the if statement of your script works. The value of the cell "K1" and the values of the cells `K4:K" of "K3:K" are compared. But if you want to modify this, please tell me.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Optimizing Scripts for Better Performance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_common_tasks#OptimizeScripts)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you - your interpretation is correct - and the range starts from row 3. I get the same response as the other answer - when I run the script, the Script execution log reports that the trigger completed and there were no logs available for execution but I have several rows that equal today.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. If the problem for resolving your issue is still left in my answer, can I ask you about the detail information of it? And also, can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: I set some of the dates in column K3:K to equal the date in K1 then ran the script but didn't receive any emails. When I looked at the Apps Script Dashboard, the status of the function is 'completed' but "No Logs available for execution". My goal is to create a Health & Safety database for the Company I work for. I need the emails to automatically alert managers when a task is due.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. About your question, I could understand that you want to remove the error message of the bottom of your question. If my understanding is correct, at first, can I ask you whether the error message could be removed? At first, I would like to resolve the issue of your question. How about  this?

Comment: it's not an error message. Emails are not being sent so when I check if the script worked, in the Apps Script Dashboard it says "Completed" and under that says "No Logs available for execution".

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could confirm that your issue of your question was resolved.

Comment: @McChief About your new issue, the value of K1 is compared with the values of the column K in your script. When both values are the same, script in the if statement is run. I think that script for comparing is no problem. But, values of yesterday 20191127 and today 20191128 are not included in your Spreadsheet. By this, the script in the if statement is not run. If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your question, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, users including me can think of the issue and solution. At that time, please close this question.

Comment: My spreadsheet is not different from my question. My original question is that I want the script to send emails when column K = K1 and it isn't. The question is therefore not resolved.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. You are using the shared Spreadsheet. I could understand like this. About `I want the script to send emails when column K = K1`, in your shared Spreadsheet, now the value of `=TODAY()` in cell K1 is not included in the column K3:K. By this, the script in the if statement is not run. If you want to test for running the script, how about copying the value of the cell K3 to K1? By this, the script is run.

Comment: Thank you - I just tried that and still no email and the Apps Script Dashboard again says "Completed" and under that says "No Logs available for execution"

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could confirm that the script in the if statement is run. About your new issue, when `emailAddress` of `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);` is not correct, the email is not sent. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the emails you use. So as a test, how about putting `emailAddress = "### your email ###";` before `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);`? By this, you can test for sending the email.

Comment: Thank you - did that - still no email. Also, all of the data in the rows of the "H&S" Review" sheet is correct including my email addresses.

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. I cannot understand `still no email`. I think that `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messageBody);` is correct. And also in my environment, the script works. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So it is required to confirm your current script. Can you provide your current `sendEmails()` for completely replicating your issue? If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: I have copied my sendEmails() code into my original question

Comment: @McChief Thank you for replying. In your Spreadsheet, the value of the cell K3 is copied to K1. By this, the values of K1 and K3 are the same. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes K1 = K3. I realised that I didnt put the var at the beginning of emailAddress = "### your email ###"; and it worked. Thank you - but the date in the email is formatted "Thu Dec 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)". I want it to be "28th November 2019"

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your time and effort to resolve my question.

Comment: That works perfectly - thank you and thank you for the explanation and your time and effort to resolve my question.